# Fetch data retorna undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs

estaba siguiendo un tutorial de JS y me encontré con este error.
Estoy tratando de hacer fetch usando una API de Pokemons, por alguna razón siempre me retorna undefined.
Me gustaría aclarar que recien estoy empezando con esto así que no sé casi nada sobre el tema, si alguien me pudiera ayudar se los agradecería :)

```
import React, {Fragment} from 'react';

const FetchPokemon = () => {

    const mostrar = () => {
        const aux = fetchP();
        console.log(aux);
    }

    const fetchP = () => {
        fetch("https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/")
        .then(res => {
            res.json();
        })
        .then(data => {
            return data;
        });
    }
    
    return ( 
        <Fragment>
            <button onClick={mostrar}>Boton</button>
        </Fragment>
     );
}
 
export default FetchPokemon;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cuando usas [`fetch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Utilizando_Fetch) junto con [funciones "flecha"](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Funciones/Arrow_functions) debes devolver ( `return` ) los valores. El mismo puede ser:

**Explícito**

```
fetch("https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/")
  .then(res => {
    return res.json()
  })
```

**Implicito:**

```
fetch("https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/")
  .then(res => res.json())
```

Otra cosa que te estaría faltando es tener algún tipo de "state" para poder almacenar el resultado del fetch. Si estas usando [React Hooks](https://es.reactjs.org/docs/hooks-overview.html), puedes escribir el componente de la siguiente manera:

```js
const FetchPokemon = () => {

    const [pokemons, setPokemons] = React.useState(null)

    const buscar = () => {
        fetch("https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/")
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(data => setPokemons(data));
    }
    
    return ( 
        <React.Fragment>
            <button onClick={buscar}>Buscar Pokemons</button>
            <div>
              {JSON.stringify(pokemons)}
            </div>
        </React.Fragment>
     );
}
 
ReactDOM.render(<FetchPokemon />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Aclaración: [`JSON.stringify()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/JSON/stringify) lo utilizo para visualizar el objeto en cuestión.

Answer (score 1):

En la función  fetchp solo estas retornando en los then creo que también tienes que retornar dentro de la funcion

Adapta esta codigo seguramente te funcione

```
const fetchTableData = () => {
  const fetchedData = fetch('https://api.myjson.com/bins/15psn9')
    .then(result => result.json())
    .then(data => {
        return data;
    })

    return fetchedData;//retornamos la contante
}

export default fetchTableData
```

También lo puedes implementar de esta forma en la que retornarias la promesa que luego tomaría el valor

```
const fetchTableData = () => {
     /* Retornamos la función directamente*/ return fetch('https://api.myjson.com/bins/15psn9')
        .then(result => result.json())
        .then(data => {
            return data;
        })
    }

    export default fetchTableData;
```

Answer (score 0):

Intenta con esto:

```
const FetchPokemon = () => {


   const fetchP = async () => {
       let response = await fetch("https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/")
       let data = await response.json()
       return data
    }

    const mostrar = async () => {
        const aux = await fetchP();
        console.log(aux);
    }


    return ( 
        <Fragment>
            <button onClick={mostrar}>Aumentar</button>
        </Fragment>
    );
}
```

Evité usar `then()` ya que con `async/await` el código es más legible.

Explicación:

Tienes que usar `async/await` debido a que `fetch()` retorna una promesa. Básicamente el código se 'pausa' esperando a `fecth()`, y una vez que este retorne algo se guarda en `response`, luego se usa `.json()` que transforma la respuesta en un objeto y lo guarda en `data`, y por último retorna `data`.

En `mostrar` también debes usar `async/await` ya que debes esperar a que `fetchP` haga todas sus cosas y retorne la data.

Una observación: `fetchP` debe ir antes de `mostrar` ya que no debes usar variables y funciones que aún no haz declarado.

Comment: Muchas gracias, me sirvió!